# How to properly load different arrays of items into vuetify's v-data-iterator?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

```
<v-data-iterator
   :items="isShop ? products : isFavorite ? favorites : shoppingCart"
   ...
   ... >
```

In the script i have three buttons that set everything to false except the boolean for the array i want to have.
Like this:

```
openFavorite() {
  this.isShop = false;
  this.isCart = false;
  this.isFavorite = true;
},
```

```
data: () => ({
  isShop: true,
  isFavorite: false,
  products: [],
  favorites: [],
  shoppingCart: [],
})
```

What happens now is that by pressing favorite it doesn't display any of my saved products. And throws an error:

> Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "justify".

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `computed`:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    active: 'products',
    products: [1, 2, 3],
    favorites: [4, 5, 6],
    shoppingCart: [7, 8, 9],
  }),
  computed: {
    items() {
      return this[this.active]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div> {{items}}
  </div>
  <button @click="active = 'favorites'">Set to 'favorites'</button>
</div>
```